# Double integral with three variables

Tags: integration, volume

I have a difficulty calculating the volume of a solid that is between $$z=0,y=0,x=0,
x+y+z=2 , y^2=1-z$$ .
How can I work this with double integral cause draw this its difficult.

Comment: Do you know how to graph $x+y+z  = 2$ and $y^2 = 1 - z$?

Comment: What have you done so far in terms of solving the problem? Depending on what order of variables you use, there are different ways in which the problem resolves.

Comment: I think my graph is write but i cant sketch the D region in the xy plane.In my graph $$1-y^2$$ is inside $$2-x-y$$ am i right? @MathNewbie

Comment: Well if they're asking for the volume of the solid that's in the first octant and lies above $z = 1-y^2$ and below $z = 2-x-y$, then sure, that would be the solid you want to look at.

Comment: It asks about the general volume between all this.I really cant figure it out and it gives as a result $$V=49/60$$ if this helps you what it wants.

Comment: @user3247715 i can help you with theese lectures https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Solution assumes diagram is drawn but OP is encouraged to draw it out, it's not too hard as long as you go step-by-step.

The best way to do this is to draw it so that the $yz$-plane is parallel to your piece of paper. Then draw your $x+y+z = 2$ plane. After that, draw more parabolas, $z = 1-y^2$, at different points on the $x$-axis with $x \geq 0$. Try to imagine a long mountain ($z = 1- y^2$) getting cut off by the plane, $ x+y+z = 2$.

Once you've got your diagram, use ideas of 'slices' (learnt from double integrals) to construct a triple integrals. This is how I view triple integrals, i.e. extend ideas from double integrals.

Imagine you are chopping a cucumber, slice by slice with a sharp knife. Then triple integrals is can be viewd like this:

$$\underbrace{\int \int}_{\text{area of each slice}} \overbrace{\int}^{\text{how far you cut}}. \tag{1}$$

Similarly,
$$\overbrace{\int}^{\text{how far you cut}}\underbrace{\int \int}_{\text{area of each slice}}. \tag{2}$$

With a diagram, this construction is extremely easy. The area of each slice can be obtained from computing the double integral of the parabola,
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-z} dydz.$$
How far we cut is where the long mountain generated by $z = 1- y^2$ is cut, 
$$\int_0^{2 - y - z} dx.$$

Use $(1)$, reason why is left for you ponder, to yield
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-z} \int_0^{2-y-z} dydz dx = \dots = \frac{49}{60}.$$

Computation verified via Wolfram Alpha Triple Integral widget.

**Remark**: This is ONE way to find the volume through integration, there are many variations to this method.